# Change ul background when li is hovered or active

Tags: jquery, css, background, html-lists, background-image

I am working on this new wordpress theme and now i have the following question. If you look here: http://www.client-szs.nl/fatih you see the main menu. If i click or hover on, let say, Blog, i want the ul background to change and move all the way over to the word blog. This also goes for the other items in the menu. So every li has a different ul background position.

Comment: nothing really heavy, because i don't know any js or much php, so mostly css/html, but that is never going to work. I have just been thinking, googling and asking friends :D

Comment: http://jsbin.com/emexug/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Easier way, if you like, just use only css, See DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/DZRUu/

## Use these css, your active menu will be changed like in DEMO.

```
.mainnav ul {
    background:#D11F28;
    background-position: -730px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid;
    min-height: 48px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    width:100%;   
}
.mainnav ul li {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', serif;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding:9px 5px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 3%;   
}
.mainnav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;      
}
.mainnav ul li.current_page_item a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#D11F28;    
}
.mainnav ul li.current_page_item{
    background:#F2F2F2;    
}
```

Comment: maybe it's me but i don't see what you mean here ? Doesn't this just change the li backgrounds ? I need it to change the ul background when a li is hovered upon and made active. again, maybe i'm missing something here :D

Comment: you are using WP, right. And you want to move white ul background on any li active, right. What I suggest is instead of moving ul background (slope white background), to use css white color background. (if you like to.) Because you need to detect the li active, but ul don't have any active state, only li has. That is why.

Comment: Your ul background is here...http://www.client-szs.nl/fatih/wp-content/themes/fatih1/images/mainnav_bg.png...  if you move this, other li (in front of active li) will be white background.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with jquery:

```
$('li').hover(function() { //mouseover
     $('ul').css('background', '#000');
}, function() { //mouseout
     $('ul').css('background', '#fff');
});
```

Obs: The code is not tested.